# Weka classifier see the results for each line

Tags: weka

I used the naive bayes classifier 10 cross validation. Is there a way to see the result for each line? I tried to ran an test set on the model but still couldn't find a way to see the result I need, I only found a summary for each attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after the test predictions from the model?  If so, click on the 'More Options...' box and Select 'Output Predictions'.

[image: Classifier Evaluation Options]

Hope this helps!